# Debian Jessie unable to read blu-ray

Tags: linux, debian, blu-ray

I've just installed a Pioneer BDC-207DBK blu-ray drive into my Debian Jessie media/file server.  The idea being I want to rip my DVD/Blu-ray collection to the hard drives and access them from within my network.

The drive itself is reading DVDs without issue, but won't read Blu ray drives.

I get the following information for the drive when I run `hwinfo`

```
69: SCSI 100.0: 10602 CD-ROM (DVD)
  [Created at block.249]
  Unique ID: KD9E.ZlUAb_nX_38
  Parent ID: w7Y8.q8BnP6yP4VA
  SysFS ID: /class/block/sr0
  SysFS BusID: 1:0:0:0
  SysFS Device Link: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata2/host1/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0
  Hardware Class: cdrom
  Model: "PIONEER BD-ROM  BDC-207D"
  Vendor: "PIONEER"
  Device: "BD-ROM  BDC-207D"
  Revision: "1.00"
  Driver: "ata_piix", "sr"
  Driver Modules: "ata_piix"
  Device File: /dev/sr0 (/dev/sg1)
  Device Files: /dev/sr0, /dev/cdrom, /dev/cdrw, /dev/disk/by-id/ata-PIONEER_BD-ROM_BDC-207D, /dev/dvd, /dev/dvdrw
  Device Number: block 11:0 (char 21:1)
  Features: CD-R, CD-RW, DVD, DVD-R, DVD-RW, DVD-R DL, DVD+R, DVD+RW, DVD+R DL, BD
  Drive status: no medium
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #34 (IDE interface)
  Drive Speed: 125
```

I've already ran the following to install items:
`apt-get install build-essential libc6-dev libssl-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libqt4-dev curl vlc`

I have handbrake already installed for ripping, and have installed MakeMKV.

When I load a disk into the drive for MakeMKV to detect, it does the "reading" but returns the Type as "No disc".

I've spent the last few hours looking round google to see if I could get it working, but haven't been able to.  How can I get Debian to read the blu-ray discs?

Answer (score 1):

After posting this and doing some digging, I've found that the issue isn't necessarily with Debian or Linux at all.  It's a blu-ray encryption issue.

All of the instructions online I'd seen had linked to a KEYDB.cfg file on the VLC website to be placed in the ~/.config/aacs folder.  This is a basic general file which needs additional keys added to it to read specific discs.

Following some digging, I found a larger KEYDB.cfg file on http://www.labdv.com/aacs/KEYDB.cfg which needs copying to the ~/.congig/aacs folder.

Once this was added in, it started reading blu-ray discs.  I guess it needs the keys for specific discs; but general purpose blu-ray players have a way of generating the keys based on some information they can read from the disc itself.